# AWS Pipeline: Staging local files to S3 failed. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

Here's my setup:
I am trying to copy files from an external Webserver to a S3 Bucket using the DataPipeline.
To do this I'm using the ShellCommandActivity which uses a script to Download the files to the Output-Bucket specified in the Pipeline. In the script I use the environment variable ${OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR} to adress the bucket. Of course I turned 'staging' to true in my pipeline.
When the script finishes, the state of the Activity becomes "FAILED" with following Error:

> Staging local files to S3 failed. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

When I look in the stdout file, I can see that my script finished sucessfully, only the staging to the bucket did not work.

I recon this could be an permission problem with the bucket but I have no idea which things I have to change!

I came across some discussions, where people got this error because the path to the bucket was configured wrong, so this is how I did it in the Pipeline Datanode Directory Path:

> s3://testBucket

Is this correct?

I would appreciate any help here!

Comment: You might also try it with a trailing slash. As I recall the api can be kind of picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the datanode directory Path: It cannot be just a bucket, but HAS to be a directory inside a bucket.
Like this:

> s3://testBucket/test

Great work with the error messages, Amazon!